# Pass array from .env to docker-compose.yml to Dockerfile to bash script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I created a custom docker container, which calls a startup script. That script requires some data, which is stored in my `.env` file.

All variables required by all files are stored in `.env`, and that is where I want to keep it. I can pass variables this way without error... it's only *arrays* that I can't pass correctly.

`.env`:

```
FOO=1                # blah
BAR='bar'            # this does blah
MYARRAY=(
  hello              # blah
  world              # blah
)
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
mycontainer:
  env_file: .env
  build:
    context: .
    args:                           # pass variables into dockerfile
      FOO: ${FOO}
      MYARRAY: ${MYARRAY}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM some_app
ARG FOO
ARG MYARRAY
ENV \
  FOO=$FOO \
  MYARRAY=$MYARRAY                # pass variables into script
CMD [ "myscript.sh" ]
```

`myscript.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -Eeuo pipefail
echo "$FOO"                                        # works
for i in "${MYARRAY[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done       # <---- problem is here
```

The array does not arrive intact in the script - it arrives as `"("`. This is because it is "translated" from ini to yaml to dockerfile syntax to bash.

How do I escape/format the stuff in `.env` so that it arrives in the bash script correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `declare -p` output and transmit the array as plain text.

```
MYARRAY=(hello world)
```

Later in your script:

```
declare -a MYARRAY="$MYARRAY"
printf "%s\n" "${MYARRAY[@]}"
```

Bash arrays is an extension by bash, it's not supported anywhere else. Environment variables can contain only text, a value. Pass anything more complicated using text properly escaped and extracted with `declare -p` (or even functions with `declare -f`). For hard cases you can prepare (or even autogenerate from some script) the array with the help of `printf "%q"`:

```
hardarray=('!@#\''\' "space space")
printf "%q" "$(declare -p hardarray | cut -d= -f2-)" # put the output in .env file
# then add in your .env file:
hardarray=\(\[0\]=\"\!@#\\\\\\\\\"\ \[1\]=\"space\ space\"\)
# then later read the array in your script:
declare -a hardarray="$hardarray"
```

I believe passing multiline strings via env_file in docker-compose is impossible. I would just advise to generate it from a shell script (but sadly, this adds another stage to the build process).

Comment: Thanks! This works when I declare the array as a single-line string `MYARRAY="( hello world )"` but does not work when it is multiline like in my code above. It needs to be multiline because it's huge and also needs to be commented. Can I use your approach with a multiline array / string?

Comment: You have to check, docker has un-intuitive comment parsing. So something like... edited. I don't think you can put multiline in env_file alltogether. Best solution - just generate .env file with `declare -p` from a bash script before running docker... Ach no, `For example if the value is surrounded by quotes (as is often the case of shell variables), the quotes are included in the value passed to Compose.`  - so you have to remove the quotes and I believe it's impossible to put multiline variables in an .env_file.

Comment: Tried your update thanks... It still doesn't work. The multiline is the real problem. I also tried to use `foo \` at the end of each line but that didn't help. I'll look into the docker manual, maybe this isn't possible :( Thanks again

Comment: This probably isn't possible... sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: That time was not wasted ; )

Comment: Just checked the [docker-compose repo](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3527) and looks like multiline strings in `.env` isn't supported - the engine only reads the first line!! :-(